# Data is not getting

Tags: c#

Here I used database connection with dataset, but i am not getting the data.

can you please help me any error in the following code

```
              string con = @"Data Source=HA-INT13\SQL2008;" + "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;database=AdventureWorks;user=sa;password=sa123";               
             dsReports = new DataSet();
             daAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dbo.Employees",con);
             SqlCommandBuilder cmdbldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(daAdapter);
             daAdapter.Fill(dsReports,"dbo.Employee");
```

Thanks,
Rajasekhar

Comment: Do you need to open the database connection? `daAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Open()`?  Also, you have specified your database name twice, first is `Initial Catalog=` and then `database=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i am seeing you added wrong sql connection strings, Inital Catlog, Database are showned twice.  [Connection String for Sql 2008](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

```
str ConnString = "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the answer but from what I know you only use

```
Integrated Security=true
```

when you are using windows accounts. If you want the username and password you are passing to be used you need to remove the Integrated Security part of the connection string.

I could be totally wrong but I think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the "dbo.Employee" parameter and go

```
dAdapter.Fill(dsReports)
```